# real analysis (derivative of fuction of 1 real variable, extremum points) challenging 2 problems

Tags: real-analysis

I tried to construct 2 proofs for the following challenging problems in real analysis, but I completely stuck. I prepare for Putnam competition and I do regularly some difficult problems for preparation . Here are the problems (any **help/solutions to these problems very appreciated**):

1. Let g be the function of 1 real variable $x$ that $f\in C^{n}(\mathbb{R})$ (where $n\in \mathbb{N}$). Prove that if function g has exactly $n+1$ extremum points (i.e maxima or minima), then: there exists $d\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(g(d)) = 0$.
2. Prove or disprove: There exists a function of 1 real variable $g$ such that $g$ has uncountably many extrema in its domain(i.e maxima or minima).

Comment: These should be separated into two separate questions, not combined into one.  Further, the title of the question should say something about the question itself.  There are tens of thousands of real analysis questions here.  What makes this question different from those should be clear at a glance from reading the title.

Comment: $g(x)=1,$ $x\in\mathbb{R}$ has uncountably many extrema.

Comment: For 1, what is $n$? Should  that be $m$? (also: Rolle's Theorem)

Comment: Sorry for typos. Obviously, ther should be consistency in putting n. Sorry!

Comment: JMoravitz, thx for your feeback! Title of content improved. Is better now?

Answer (score 2):

1) Proof by induction: The theorem is true for $m=1$ because if it has exactly one extrema then $\lim_{x\to-\infty}g(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ then we can find two points with the same value of the function, and so by Rolle's Theorem we are done.

Assume it's true for $m$, and let $g$ be an $m+1$ times differentiable function. Then $g'(x)$ has exactly $m+1$ extrema, and so by induction $(g')^{(m)}$ takes on the value of $0$ somewhere. But that's the same as saying that $g^{(m+1)}$ takes on the value of zero and we are done.

2) the constant function works, but there are non-trivial examples too. Consider the indicator function of the cantor set. We very point is an extrema. There are in fact even continuous non-trivial examples, check out the [Weierstrass Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

Comment: Tried constant fucntion in problem 2. But how to formulate rigorous proof in this problem? Any further help very appreciated!

Comment: @MIT What exactly is your definition of extrema

Comment: By extrema, I mean maximam and minima of fucntion. I was tought in classes that extermum covers the definition of maxima and minima. Hope this helps.

Comment: The function $f(x)=0$ is never smaller than $0$, so $0$ is a minimum

Comment: Yes, this is obviously correct.

Comment: Don't see hint from your response...

Comment: Well, the function then has a min everywhere it is equal to zero. But that's all of R